# Production ready derivative from LFS

Tags: linux, command-line, kernel

I've recently started delving into [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) and have been wondering if there are any popular or well-used distros that have been derived from LFS or [BLFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/). There are a few of completed projects on Github but seem to be lacking in any documentation.

Therefore, I was wonder about the use of this project and whether it is used purely as a tool to learn a few of the internals of the OS or whether a "modern" OS can be build on top of it. Any suggestions/links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, Linux from Scratch (LFS) is designed NOT to be a *derived distro*.  You are doing the derivation yourself!  You could say, any GNU/Linux distro that you see is derived from the same (or more) sources as LFS.